# How to edit HTML textarea content by using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[http://neomx.iwedding.co.kr/roundcube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNmCc.jpg)

I tried to modify the content of textarea especially the tracking number. What I want to do is to change "9400111206213835724810" to "487289527385922090". However I kept got this message "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable".

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "composebody"))
) 
driver.find_element(By.ID, "composebody").clear()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "composebody").send_keys("happy")
```

Full XPATH of the textarea was

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/textarea
```

Inspect

[image]

Now I'm wondering that it is allowed to modify a textarea in HTML.
Could you please what should I try more or let me know some useful reference of it?

Answer (score 0):

In style attribute you can see that visibility value is "hidden". That's why you cannot use that element. probably there is should be another textarea element that is visible(sometimes elements can be duplicated for different size of screens)